# Match word to word content in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to regex a content from a list in python,

Content is like:

```
garbage text
garbage text
Heading 1:
  important content abx
  important content xvy
  important content
  important content xyz
  important content zed
Heading 2:
 more content
```

I want to grab content from "Heading 1" to "zed"

Thing's i already try:

```
regex = r'Heading 1.*?zed'
```

but it doesn't work for multi-line

Comment: What is your data structure (you say it's a list, but regex is for strings)? What was the output of your attempt? Also, do you need to use a regex?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Already Solved Below,
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `re.findall` with the following pattern, in dot all mode:

```
\bHeading 1:.*?(?=Heading \d+|$)
```

Dot all mode will ensure that the `.*?` will match across lines.  The lookahead at the end will stop either before the start of the next heading, or the end of the input, whichever occurs first.

Sample script:

```
inp = """garbage text
garbage text
Heading 1:
  important content abx
  important content xvy
  important content
  important content xyz
  important content zed
Heading 2:
 more content"""

matches = re.findall(r'\bHeading 1:.*?(?=Heading \d+|$)', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(matches[0])
```

This prints:

```
Heading 1:
  important content abx
  important content xvy
  important content
  important content xyz
  important content zed
```